# How to set profile picture

Tags: php, html

If im clicking the set profile pic means,i want to set that image on profile pic,which image i have set that image value i have to store 1 remaining values i have to store 0,in my code it will insert in 0 only

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM useralbum WHERE isprofilepic IN ('1') AND ssmid='$ssmid'");
$count = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($count == '1'){
 while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
   $profileid = $row['id'];
 }
 $profile=mysql_query("UPDATE useralbum SET isprofilepic='0' WHERE id='$profileid'");
 if($profile){
     echo "SUCCESS";
 }
 else{
    echo "ERROR".mysql_error(); 
 } 
}  

else{    
 $newprofile=mysql_query("UPDATE useralbum SET isprofilepic='1' WHERE isprofilepic='".$_SESSION['profile']."'");
  if($newprofile){
     echo "SUCCESS";
 }
 else{
    echo "ERROR".mysql_error(); 
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is issue in your condition. If there is previous profile pic
. Then it will go in this block. It will never go in else part so never set 1 for new profile pic.

```
if($count == '1'){
 while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
   $profileid = $row['id'];
 }
 $profile=mysql_query("UPDATE useralbum SET isprofilepic='0' WHERE id='$profileid'");
 if($profile){
     echo "SUCCESS";
 }
 else{
    echo "ERROR".mysql_error(); 
 } 
}
```

In this you don't change new profile pic record after updating previous record. If there is no profile pic set before then it works. it will go in else part. but what if profile pic is already set and you change it. so change you r condition.

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM useralbum WHERE isprofilepic="1" AND ssmid='$ssmid'");
$count = mysql_num_rows($sql);

//If there is already profile pic set then if block executes and set it to 0.
if($count == '1'){
 while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
   $profileid = $row['id'];
 }
 $profile=mysql_query("UPDATE useralbum SET isprofilepic='0' WHERE id='$profileid'");
 if($profile){
     echo "SUCCESS";
 }
 else{
    echo "ERROR".mysql_error(); 
 } 
}  

   //After setting previous pic 0, update new pic to 1. (This will works on both cases if already profile pic is set and there is first time setting profile pic )
 $newprofile=mysql_query("UPDATE useralbum SET isprofilepic='1' WHERE ssmid='$ssmid'");
  if($newprofile){
     echo "SUCCESS";
 }
 else{
    echo "ERROR".mysql_error(); 
 }
```

will gives you accurate record. Try this one.

Comment: I cann't understand jazz,where i have to change and where i had did mistake,could you update your query

Comment: Nothing happend jazz 0 only inserted ,1 is not inserting

Comment: what value is `$_SESSION['profile']`. is there ssmid? if yes then your query is wrong at the time of set `1`.
$newprofile=mysql_query("UPDATE useralbum SET isprofilepic='1' WHERE ssmid='$ssmid'");
  if($newprofile){

Comment: $_SESSION['profile'] value is photoname like 5650111b7919a.png

Comment: ok and what value you are storing in isprofilepic? 1/0 OR profile pic name? because in  `$newprofile=mysql_query("UPDATE useralbum SET isprofilepic='1' WHERE isprofilepic='".$_SESSION['profile']."'");`  you are comparing with wrong field. if isprofilepic is 0/1 then your `isprofilepic='".$_SESSION['profile']."` will not update your record. as you said `$_SESSION['profile']` is photoname.

Comment: I want to store,if set profilepic means store 1,otherwise remaining all should be 0

Comment: then stop comparing your profilephoto value `$_SESSION['profile']` with `isprofilepic`. because it is always 0 if no profile pic set and 1 if profilepic set.  there should be field name in which you save images name.

Comment: now where i have to change can u plz update query jazz

Comment: tell me your field name which you use for save image name and field which you use for 0/1